# GPU driver restart just in PCI-E 16x slot

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, gpu, display-driver

My specs are these:

- i5 3570k
- 2x 4Gb G-skill DDR3
- MSI Geforce 770GTX
- 650W PSU (Inter Tech Energon EPS-650W - http://www.inter-tech.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=615%3Aenergon-eps-650w&catid=125%3Aausland-atx-Power%20supplye&Itemid=542&lang=en )
- Asus P8Z77-V LX Mobo

So, I find my problem rather strange. The nvidia Display drivers keep restarting **sometimes only when I start a new stuff** (ranging from start chrome, my computer or battelfield 4). **This happens just when the GPU is seated in the main PCIE-16x slot**. If the GPU is seated in the secondary PCIE-4x slot I never ever get a crash...

Another intereseting thing : If I start MSI Afterburner and for my GPU in it's first state (like under load) I won't get crashes.

So this makes my think it has a problem while switching from idle to another state. But why does this not happend when the GPU is seated in the PCIE-4X slot ?? So that makes me think maybe it's a PSU problem  ? But the GPU should not use more power while in 16X slot, right ? Or maybe a faulty MOBO ?

I have already tried :

- 5 different nvidia drivers, all same result
- updated BIOS
- reseated RAM, GPU
- check RAM for faulty segments
- same problem in WIN7 and WIN8.1 on fresh maschines

Unfortunately I cannot try the GPU in another computer and do not have any spare GPU, MOBO or anything else.

So my 2 questions to sum it up:

1. What seems more likely to cause this behaviour ?
2. Any idea on how to fix this without replacing hardware ?

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean install of the drivers? Check the BIOS, specifically under the PCI interface menu, to see if you can find any clues.

Comment: @happy_soil yes I have also use driver sweeper. I have checked the BIOS a lot and I do not see anything suspicious

Comment: It could be a hardware fault between the GPU, motherboard, or even the PSU (not feeding enough power to the GPU?). You'll need to further drill down on this matter piece by piece, and unfortunately you're going to need spare components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have bouth a good PSU and now the problem is gone. I am not 100% sure I understand why the GPU needed less power in the PCIE-4X slot, but I have also seen that the given PSU did not natively had a 6pin PCIE and a connector was used from 2x molex.

Perhaps because a connector was used and given the fact that the PSU was crap it did not need enough power to supply the higher bandwidth given by the PCIE-16X speed...

Anyway, if someone could explain the problem would be much appreciated, I find this interesting.